# How to use IHttpContextAccessor in Autofac Multitenant?

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, autofac, multi-tenant

What's the correct way to pass an IHttpContextAccessor into the multi-tenant strategy with Autofac?  I can't seem to find this documented anywhere.  I tried constructing an instance of the HttpContextAccessor and passing it into the strategy, but this results in the `HttpContext` always being null.

**Startup**

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddMvc();
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.Populate(services);

    var container = builder.Build();
    var strategy = new FooTenantStrategy(new HttpContextAccessor());
    var mtc = new MultitenantContainer(strategy, container);
    Startup.ApplicationContainer = mtc;
    return new AutofacServiceProvider(mtc);
}
```

**Program**

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        // This enables the request lifetime scope to be properly spawned from
        // the container rather than be a child of the default tenant scope.
        // The ApplicationContainer static property is where the multitenant container
        // will be stored once it's built.
        .UseAutofacMultitenantRequestServices(() => Startup.ApplicationContainer)
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging through some source code I found a [sample](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.AspNetCore.Multitenant/blob/9d6a0272dc598ff64f5354f66adbfb876ded9031/samples/Sandbox/QueryStringTenantIdentificationStrategy.cs) from a test that does the trick:

```
var strategy = new FooTenantStrategy(container.Resolve<IHttpContextAccessor>(), container.Resolve<ILogger<SonicFoundryTenantStrategy>>());
```

The key part being pulling the context from the container that was previously built.